# Initial Boundary Value Problem for Wave Equation$ u_{tt} = 4u_{xx}$.

Tags: boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

Solve the initial boundary value problem:
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} 
u_{tt} &= 4u_{xx} \quad   x > 0, \, t > 0 \\
u(x, 0) &= x^2/8, \\ 
u_t(x, 0) &= x \quad  x ≥ 0 \\
u(0,t) &= t^2, \quad t ≥ 0.\end{aligned} \end{equation}

I don't think I can use d'Almbert's formula, so I'm stuck. Some help would be nice!

Comment: And why you think that?

Comment: You can't use d'Almbert's formula because the boundary condition is not 0. @Quintic

Comment: So I tried using that and I just got lost after that. @Quintic

Comment: did you try separating the variables?

Comment: No... I just tried applying the conditions @Quintic

Comment: Why is the approach in the answer to your last question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533025/initial-boundary-value-problem-for-wave-equation not possible anymore?