# Initial Boundary Value Problem for a Wave Equation $u_{tt}=4u_{xx}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Solve the initial boundary value problem:
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} 
u_{tt} &= 4u_{xx} \quad   x > 0, \, t > 0 \\
u(x, 0) &= x^2/8, \\ 
u_t(x, 0) &= x \quad  x ≥ 0 \\
u(0,t) &= t^2, \quad t ≥ 0.\end{aligned} \end{equation}

This question is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542437/initial-boundary-value-problem-for-wave-equation-u-tt-4u-xx). Seeing that that question is not active, how would we approach this?

Comment: How do you normally set about solving the wave equation? Surely you have ideas you can contribute.

Comment: Would we be using separation of variables @Ted? I've been reading off [here](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/separation.pdf) trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, separation of variables (and Fourier series) is the standard approach. It's in plenty of textbooks.